# Saving PDF file uiwebview

Tags: pdf, uiwebview

I have a web page that generates a costume pdf file using fpdf php library. I can then view, download, zoom in, zoom out that file (pdf file) in my web page. It works fine using a web browser, but I've problem in saving the pdf file from a webview in Objective C. I am working on Mac OS X 10.6 using XCode 3.2. I've an application that has a webview that is linked to that web page. the application runs on client machine. All the options except saving the file work fine in the web view. How can I get out of this problem.

Thanx to all in advance.

Comment: You have to first convert pdf file to NSData and write NSData to path using [pdfData writeToFile: automatically:]; method

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I've implemented all the pdf functionalities in php, and it works fine in a web browser, on the other side I've a webview that is just linked to that php page. I want the webview app to use the php pdf functionalities, and I don't want to convert pdf file to NSData. the app show the pdf data, because it is just linked to a php page, but the saving option dose not work when I try to access that page from my web view app.

Comment: ok.... now i understand ur question

Comment: can't any one solve the problem????